# Display the name of all files with home directory which is smaller (in size) than 10 KB but bigger than 5 KB

Tags: command-line, ls

Display the name of all files with home directory which is smaller
(in size) than 10 KB but bigger than 5 KB.  using Linux comand.

pls help me

Answer (score 0):

A [command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to do this is ...

```
find . -type f -size +5c -size -10c
```

- where . searches from the directory you start the command.
- -type f will find files and not directories
- -size +5c means larger than 5 bytes.
- -size -10c means smaller than 10 bytes.

Comment: Thnaku you. @Rinzwind

Comment: How do i display a sorted list of all files in the home directory?